# In jquery-ui 1.9, how do you create new tabs dynamically?

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

According to the upgrade guide for jquery-ui 1.9 tabs - http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-add-and-remove-methods-and-events-use-refresh-method - when adding new tabs dynamically, you only have to do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id='tabs'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#tab1'>#1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id='tab1'></div>
</div>
<button id='add-tab'>Add tab</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#tabs").tabs();

    $("button#add-tab").click(function() {

        var num_tabs = $("div#tabs ul li").length + 1;

        $("div#tabs ul").append(
            "<li><a href='#tab" + num_tabs + "'>#" + num_tabs + "</a></li>"
        );

        $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
    });                    
});
```

However when I try change between the newly created tabs, I get the following error in firebug:

> jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.

If I understand correctly, this error means that the actual tab panel isn't being created (and thus there's a mismatch between the nav panel and the tab panel). But the upgrade guide makes no mention of creating a tab panel.

So I'm assuming that either I'm doing it wrong or that the upgrade guide is incomplete. Please clarify.

Interestingly enough, when removing tabs, the upgrade guide says you have to explicitly remove both the list item from the nav panel as well as the tab panel explicitly, so I'm wondering if the same applies to adding tabs.

Comment: Copy-pasted your exact code in a jsFiddle, and it works without any problems.

    http://jsfiddle.net/rMGCM/

Are you sure this is all you're doing?

Comment: Thanks Krippie. Did you try change between the tabs? If you do, you'll see the mismatch error. The only thing that fixes it is adding: $("div#tabs").append("<div id='tab" + num_tabs + "'>Tab " + num_tabs + "</div>"); But this isn't mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Official guide with source on how to add and remove Tabs dynamically in JQuery UI available here: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The guide must be incomplete, you need to add a tab panel

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#tabs").tabs();

    $("button#add-tab").click(function() {

        var num_tabs = $("div#tabs ul li").length + 1;

        $("div#tabs ul").append(
            "<li><a href='#tab" + num_tabs + "'>#" + num_tabs + "</a></li>"
        );
$("div#tabs").append(
            "<div id='tab" + num_tabs + "'>#" + num_tabs + "</div>"
        );
        $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
    });                    
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/ujUu2/)

Comment: Thanks axrwkr. That works well. Can't say I'm a big fan of the extra steps we have to take to add tabs now. I much preferred the old way of using $("div#tabs").tabs("add", ...); Sure this new approach is more flexible, but the old approach was quick and easy for those simple cases that didn't require flexibility.

Comment: It is a not good idea with `num_tabs`, why? For example we open 3 tabs. So the last have `num_tabs = 3`, then we close the first tab with `num_tabs=1`, now when we try add new tab, the count of **tabs = 3**     `var num_tabs = $("div#tabs ul li").length + 1;` so we try add new tab with **same id** which already exists. So it is a **WRONG** way. I need some time to resolve and will print my code below.

Comment: @Jek-fdrv I understand your reasoning, though I feel that you're over engineering if there isn't a requirement to remove tabs. In that sense the solution I have put forward is the right way, because it does what needs to be done and no more than that.

Comment: @Jek-fdrv see [Writing robust code vs. overengineering](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110227/writing-robust-code-vs-overengineering)

Answer (score 4):

After each tab addition you have to create a div for showing content like for creating `tab number 2`

```
$("div#tabs").append("<div id='tab"+num_tabs+"'></div>");
```

check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AJDLt/1/

Comment: Thanks Rohan. Yeah this is pretty much the same conclusion I arrived at. I'm just wondering why this wasn't mentioned in the docs. Any idea?

Comment: You should use the method `add` of `jquery ui` `$('div#tabs').tabs('add', 'tab'+num_tabs, num_tabs);` check the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/AJDLt/3/ 
In this case you don't have to apply your own logic it automatically add a new tab, you can create its id by your logic.

Comment: Hey Rohan, the ''add'' method was deprecated in jquery-ui 1.9 and removed altogether in 1.10. Hence this question on SO.

Comment: Ok, but I think there may be any alternative for this.

Answer (score 4):

So, the right way to do this like a top answer but without nub_tabs.

```
$("div#tabs").tabs();
var tab_id = 1;
$("button#add-tab").click(function() {
    tab_id++; //It can be any id;

    $("div#tabs ul").append(
    '<li id="'+tab_id+'"><a href="#tab"'+tab_id+'">#"+tab_id+"</a><i class="close-tab" target="'+tab_id+'"></i></li>');
$("div#tabs").append(
    '<div id="'+tab_id+'">#'+tab_id+'</div>');
    $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
});

//Now i want to show some functions from my code;
//It will not work for you, just want show the idea;

//No clone tabs

function if_tab_exist(thisI) { //thisI - contains some id, title and text for tab content.
    var tab_id = $(thisI).attr('id');
    if(!$('.ui-tabs-nav li#'+tab_id).is('*')) {
        addTab(thisI); //Add tab function
    } else {
        var TAB_index = $('.ui-tabs-nav li#'+tab_id).index();
        $("#tabs").tabs({active: TAB_index}); //Will activate already exist tab
    }
}

//Close tab
function close_tab(tab_id) {
    $('.ui-tabs-nav i[target='+tab_id+']').parent().remove();       
    $('#tabs div#'+tab_id+']').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
}
//Events
//CLose
$("body").on('click','.ui-tabs-nav .ui-state-default i', function() {
    close_tab($(this).attr('target'));
});
//Add
$("body").on('click','.addTab', function() {
    if_tab_exist(this);
});
```

Comment: Instead of using a global tab_id you could use uniqueId (https://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/)

Answer (score 4):

It is annoying that the tabs `"add"` was removed, however jQuery is very easy to extend. Just add your own `addTab` method.

e.g. Something like this:

```
// jQuery extension method
$.fn.addTab = function (name) {
    $('ul', this).append('<li><a href="#tab-' + name + '">' + name + '</a></li>');
    $(this).append("<div id='tab-" + name + "'></div>");
    $(this).tabs("refresh");
};
```

And simply use like this:

```
$('#tabs').addTab("NewTab");
$('#tabs').addTab("Another NewTab");
$('#tabs').addTab("etc");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/AJDLt/315/

As suggested by @Andy, you need to make it use `.first()` if you nest tabs in your interface:

e.g. Something like this:

```
// jQuery extension method
$.fn.addTab = function (name) {
    $('ul', this).first().append('<li><a href="#tab-' + name + '">' + name + '</a></li>');
    $(this).append("<div id='tab-" + name + "'></div>");
    $(this).tabs("refresh");
};
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the tab you are modifying contains sub-tab panels. It also adds the tab to each of those.

Comment: Change it to "$('ul', this).first()..." to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

An example is described in more details [here](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/dynamic-tabs-using-jquery-why-and-how-to-create-it/) moreover there is a [runnable version](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation) is on jquery ui's official site with its source code.

A simple declaration could be something like the following:

```
var addTab = function (tabs, tabId, tabLabel, tabContentHtml) {
     var header = "<li><a href='#" + tabId + "'>" + tabLabel + "</a> </li>"
     tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(header);
     tabs.append("<div id='" + tabId + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>");
     tabs.tabs("refresh");
};
```

Addition of a new tab is getting easier, just type the following:

```
$("#tabs_area").tabs();
addTab($("#tabs_area"), "tab_id1", "Tab 1", "this is just test");
```

Comment: Thanks for this; I see the old code still works. It's somewhat of a shame because your solution is far more elegant. You reckon it will remain backwards compatible? Updating it across the board would be painful.