# Adding a tab dynamically using jQuery shows content in the wrong place

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using the following code to add a tab dynamically with the content cloned from another tab.

The code is based on [In jquery-ui 1.9, how do you create new tabs dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702631/in-jquery-ui-1-9-how-do-you-create-new-tabs-dynamically)

I am using Jquery 1.9

However the problem is that the cloned content is placed below the tabs and not as one of the tabs.
In addition, the new tab is non-selectable.

```
function addDynamicTab() {
    var num_tabs = $("div#tabs ul li").length + 1;
    $("div#tabs ul").append(
            "<li class='ui-state-default ui-corner-top'><a href='#tabs-" + num_tabs + "'>Tab #" + num_tabs + "</a></li>"
        );
     $("div#tabs").append("<div class='ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom' id='tabs-"+num_tabs+"'>"+$('#tabs-3').html()+"</DIV>");
     $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to JQuery1.11 solved my issue immediately