# Jquery yii CJuiTabs add new tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

Please help, i want to make like this, when i click "+" will add new tabs with same render partial 
[image]

i have a basically script like this

```
  <?php 
                $tabs=array();
                $i=0;
                $a=1;
                for ($i=0;$i<$a;$i++){
                $tabs['Persyaratan '.$a]=array(
                    'id'=>'syarattab',
                    'content'=>$this->renderPartial("_formsyarat",array('mdsyarat'=>$mdsyarat),$this));
                }
                $tabs['+']=array(
                    'id'=>'tambah');

                $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs',array(
                    'tabs'=>$tabs,
                    'options'=>array(
                        'collapsible'=>true,
                    ),
                    'id'=>'Tabs_syarat',
                ));?>
```

how can i add jquery code in tabs + ?? please help.. thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:**
[In jquery-ui 1.9, how do you create new tabs dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702631/in-jquery-ui-1-9-how-do-you-create-new-tabs-dynamically)
You can use this method, because CJui is jQuery UI plugin.

---

You can use documentation for jQuery Ui Tabs API, there is a method called "refresh".

Basic algorithm for adding new tab will be:

1. Add event on pressing plus sign, and add new content and link directly in DOM with new IDs.
2. Call "refresh" method linked above.

You can also check upgrade guide, if your CJuiTabs is using old version of jQuery UI:
http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-add-and-remove-methods-and-events-use-refresh-method

Comment: can you show me in example code or example project, thank